# AngularJS and Rails application security in AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, security, amazon-web-services, puma

I have an AngularJS front-end running on a Nginx server that sends requests to a Rails API backend running on a Puma application server. This application is running on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance.

The Rails API is listening on port 8081.

According to this architecture I had to open the HTTP port 8081 in AWS, so that I could receive the request from the front-end.

I have a domain, so It´s supposed all request should come from www.domain.com. However, I have noticed that if I use my EC2 instance name, such as, in example `http://ec2-<ip>.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/users` the Rails API is serving all my users information.

How can I avoid this security bug. Where should I block this? In AWS configuration? In my Rails API CORS configuration? Any other place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems an `Authorization` bug in your Rails API.
Who is the controller that answer to the route `/users`?
Let's say it is, for e.g., `UsersController`: in this case, you could have an action

```
def index
    @users = User.all
end
```

or something similar, that returns the information you see.
Is difficult to give you a solution, without knowing if you need this action (maybe is just auto-generated boilerplate code) or if you want simply hiding it to who is not an Administrator...
Who wrote the Back End API should fix this for you based on your specifications.

Comment: Hi,  yes, let´s suppose, I have a UserController with the method index you defined. But, it´s not an auto-generated boilerplate, but a method that could be called from my front-end (where a user is logged in).

Comment: Ok, so... you can leave it where it is, but you need to check if a user is authenticated or not. Can't help more than this without knowing your authentication process. Because the 2 application (front end and back end) are separated in two different web services, you can't use the session for authentication. You're probably using tokens or Api-key/Api-secret pair, or whatever. Still, the Back end developer should know how to manage this :) If you're not using any of them, you should for sure introduce them. This will require work on both front and back end.

Comment: I get your point. I will think about it. But so far my Rails API is like dumb, it only serve requests, it doesn´t manage authentication. This responsability is on the front-end side. I was thinking about something a bit more general, such as, you will only serve the requests that are coming from a url or a port (front-end port), I don´t know if CORS is the proper tool.

Comment: As a temporary solution yes, you can instruct the back end to accept requests only from specific IPs. You can use CORS, take a look at this [CORS with Rails](http://leopard.in.ua/2012/07/08/using-cors-with-rails/). As you will read, it's not the best solution for compatibility issues. Another solution can be setting up accesses at web-server level, but I have no idea on how to do it with Puma :(. If you can, move to Nginx also for the Rails API app (AFAIK, Puma is better for Sinatra) and take a look here to set them up: [link](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/)